# How to stop JFileChooser from opening a new window

Tags: java, jfilechooser

Currently working on a fairly simple program for school. I've been trying to teach myself how to use JFileChooser and run into a small issue. After JFileChooser is called once through it's respective button, the window opens every time any other button is pressed as well. My code is sloppy as I'm not exactly sure what all of it does, so I was wondering if there was a way to prevent the window from opening manually? I have done a lot of research and cannot seem to find anything of the sort.

Like I said before, the code is sloppy, but here it is if anyone has the time to give it a glance.

```
public class Scramble extends JFrame
{
private final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

Random randNum;

private int score = 0;
private int guess = 0;
private int totalWords;
private int currentWord;

private File file;

private ArrayList<String> originalWords = new ArrayList<>();

private JLabel labelScrambledWord = new JLabel("Unscramble");

private JTextField textUserGuess = new JTextField(28);

private JButton buttonCheck = new JButton("Check");
private JButton buttonGiveUp = new JButton("Give Up");
private JButton buttonBrowse = new JButton("Browse");

private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

public Scramble()
{
    // Sets current word to random number
    randNum = new Random();
    changeCurrentWord();

    // Sets label to scrambled word as soon as program opens
    newWord();
    mainPanel.add(labelScrambledWord);

    mainPanel.add(textUserGuess);

    buttonCheck.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    buttonGiveUp.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    buttonBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            browseButtonClicked();
        }

    });

    mainPanel.add(buttonCheck);
    mainPanel.add(buttonGiveUp);
    mainPanel.add(buttonBrowse);

    this.add(mainPanel);
}

private void browseButtonClicked()
{   
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Browse for text file");

    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Txt File", "txt");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

    int buttonVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if(buttonVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        try
        {
            readFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private void changeCurrentWord()
{
    if(originalWords.size() > 0)
    {
        currentWord = randNum.nextInt(originalWords.size());
    }
}

private void newWord()
{   
    // Checks if any words are left and then sets new word
    if(originalWords.size() > 0)
    {
        labelScrambledWord.setText(scramble(originalWords.get(currentWord)));
    }
    // Changes text field to display total score
    else if(totalWords > 0)
    {
        textUserGuess.setText("Complete: Your score is " + String.format("%.2f", (double)score/(double)totalWords) + "/" + 5);
    }
    else
    {
        textUserGuess.setText("Input text file");
    }
}

/*
 * Reads Strings from txt file
 */
private void readFile() throws IOException
{
    // Grabs txt file from path
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

    // Adds new words to ArrayList until there are none left
    while (scan.hasNext())
    {
        originalWords.add(scan.next());
    }
    totalWords = originalWords.size();
    scan.close();
}

/*
 * Returns original word given in parameters as scrambled word
 */
private String scramble(String originalWord)
{
    randNum = new Random();

    int index;

    // String that will be returned
    String scrambledWord = "";

    // Allows us to remove characters from original word after character has
    // been added to scrambled word
    String editedWord = originalWord;

    for (int count = 0; count < originalWord.length(); count++)
    {
        index = randNum.nextInt(editedWord.length());
        scrambledWord += editedWord.substring(index, index + 1);

        // Removes the character added to the scrambled word from original
        editedWord = editedWord.substring(0, index) + editedWord.substring(index + 1);
    }
    return scrambledWord;
}

/*
 * ButtonListener class to use as action listener for buttons
 */
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        // Checks which button was clicked
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Check"))
        {
            checkButtonClicked();
        }
        // Executed when "Give Up" button is pressed
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Give Up"))
        {
            giveUpButtonClicked();
        }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Browse"));
        {
            browseButtonClicked();
        }

    }

    // Executed if buttonCheck is clicked
    private void checkButtonClicked()
    {
        //Closes program if user hits another button after words are gone
        if(originalWords.size() == 0)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (textUserGuess.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(originalWords.get(currentWord)))
        {
            textUserGuess.setText("That is correct. Here is a new word to try.");

            // Removes word from list
            originalWords.remove(currentWord);

            // Sets new current word
            changeCurrentWord();

            // Adds score based on number of guesses currently
            addScore();

            // Changes word to new word
            newWord();
        }
        else
        {
            textUserGuess.setText("Sorry, that is incorrect. Please try again.");

            // Adds a guess to the count after wrong answer
            guess++;
        }
    }

    // Executed if buttonGiveUp is clicked
    private void giveUpButtonClicked()
    {

        // Closes program if user hits another button after words are gone
        if(originalWords.size() == 0)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // Displays answer to user
        textUserGuess.setText(originalWords.get(currentWord));

        // Removes word from list
        originalWords.remove(currentWord);

        // Changes current word being displayed
        changeCurrentWord();

        // Sets guess back to 0 for new word
        guess = 0;

        // Sets new scrambled word
        newWord();
    }

    /*
     * Adds to player score based on number of guesses used
     */
    private void addScore()
    {
        switch (guess)
        {
        case 0:
            score += 5;
            break;
        case 1:
            score += 3;
            break;
        case 2:
            score += 1;
            break;
        default:
            score += 0;
        }

        guess = 0;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scramble frame = new Scramble();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);

    // Prevents user from changing dimensions and causing interface to look
    // different than intended.
    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly I need some sleep. The problem was because I had two action listeners on the button and one of them was being called with the others.